# Latex bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex

I am new with Latex and I want to fix my bibliography but it doesn't work well 
this is my code of Latex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,latin1,utf8]{StyleRapport}
\include{formatAndDefs}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{latexsym}

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{slashbox,booktabs,amsmath}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1]{\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\markboth{\slshape\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\slshape\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\bsc{\chaptername~\thechapter{} :} #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} \ #1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\lhead[]{\small{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\small{\leftmark}]{}
\cfoot[\small{\thepage}]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\include{PageDeGarde}
\dominitoc
\pagenumbering{roman}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Remerciements}`
\mainmatter
\include{IntroductionGenerale}
%\mainmatter
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\include{Chapter3}
\include{Chapter4}
\include{ConclusionGenerale}
\bibliographystyle{StyleRapport}
%On ne met rien ici, ca va se faire automatiquement après remplissage du fichier Bibliographie.bib
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliographie}
%\newpage
%\printindex
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

and when I compile the `bibliography.aux` doesn't appear so please help me what to do?

I tried a lot to fixed at the begining I used

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

then I changed to 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

then I tried both of them

Comment: Are you sure, that you need all the stuff, you usepackage there? Which editor do you use?

Comment: Don't use `\include` in the preamble. Not only do you not need all the stuff you are loading, you positively need not to load some of it as you are loading e.g. the same package with different options, obsolete packages etc. Note that nobody can help much because nobody can use the code you're posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compile your `latex_filename.tex` file:

```
pdflatex latex_filename
```

Then compile the bibliography using bibtex:

```
bibtex latex_filename
```

Finally compile your `latex_filename.tex` *twice more* to update the pdf with your new bibliography and all citation call-outs:

```
pdflatex latex_filename
```

Make sure your `Bibliographie.bib` file is in the same folder as your `latex_filename.tex` file.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your answer a bit, e.g., to use backticks instead of asterisks.